# How to handle invalid/extra special characters & = in request url-SpringBoot?

Tags: spring-boot, rest, postman

I have a Rest service where get call if I send multiple invalid/extra `&` and `=` characters then also my endpoint does not throw any error. I would like to throw back `invalid request` error if url contains any extra special character like `&` or `=`.
for example:

```
    http://localhost:8080/myservice?rollNo=03456789321&school=Myschool   //This is Okay for me
    http://localhost:8080/myservice?rollNo=03456789321&school=    //should throw error as school is not having value
    http://localhost:8080/myservice?rollNo=03456789321&&&&school=Myschool 
  //should throw error as &&&& is multiple where it should only one
    http://localhost:8080/myservice?rollNo=03456789321&=   //should throw error as &= is there at end having no sence.
```

Note that , I am hitting these request from postman , and I have doubt that postman do something with these parameters, cause I am not able to find these extra characters in spring boot while debugging.

1. Any way through which i can get whole request url in my controller so that I can find out for these charecters comming?
2. Any built in springboot annotation is there to handle such a cases?

Answer (score 0):

I got my problem solved.
After lot of research , and some observation I came to know that when you pass any number of characters among `&` and `=` in request url, the rest client tools like postman , or advanced rest client will refine the url before hitting actual server and remove those extra un-necessary characters. SO if you write multiple `&&&&` or `==` charecters in url , it will consider each extra & as blank parameter and will ignore while sending final request, only of those characters which has parameter names besides it it will taken as part of refined request.

you can see in screenshot bellow:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can Use `@RequestParam` in your Spring Boot rest Controller

Something of the following

```
@GetMapping(value = "/myservice")
public boolean doSomething(@RequestParam("rollNo") Integer rollNo , @RequestParam("school") String school) {
    doValidation(rollNo,school);

    // Do Something

    return true;

  }
```

`@RequestParam` will make sure that your Url need to have these Params rollNo & school. Without it it will throw error.

But if you were to pass an empty string  like &school= in your second example. The controller will get an empty String.

You can add a basic validation layer right before you do anything in you controller to handle this condition.